How to create a Result object with only a generic error type, but no success type?
Using CSharpFunctionalExtensions, how can I create a Result type, that has an Error type, but no specific success type? (as there is already Result.IsSuccess, which is sufficient for me).
I tried this, however that looses the information about the Error generic type parameter:
private Result Validate()
{
    if(false)
    {
        return Result.Failure<Error>(new Error
        {
            Code = "ERROR_CODE",
            Message = "ERROR_MESSAGE"
        });
    }
    
    return Result.Success();
}


It sounds like you just want to discard the "success" result type. You should use UnitResult<E>. It also has the IsSuccess property you want.

Represents the result of an operation that has no return value on success, or an error on failure.

Example usage:
private UnitResult<Error> Validate()
{
    if(false)
    {
        return UnitResult.Failure<Error>(new Error
        {
            Code = "ERROR_CODE",
            Message = "ERROR_MESSAGE"
        });
    }
    
    return UnitResult.Success<Error>();
}

